# Apply one Guard to multiple routes in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

For example: to apply one middleware to multiple routes we can use:

```
export class UserModule {
    public configure(consumer: MiddlewaresConsumer) {
        consumer.apply(AuthMiddleware).forRoutes(
            { path: '/users', method: RequestMethod.GET },
            { path: '/users/:id', method: RequestMethod.GET },
            { path: '/users/:id', method: RequestMethod.PUT },
            { path: '/users/:id', method: RequestMethod.DELETE },
        );
    }
}
```

I would like apply **AuthGuard** to multiple routes, ¿ what is the best practice ? thanks ...

Currenly I use one by one decorator inside controller function like this,

```
@Get()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
async findAll(@Request() request): Promise<User[]> {
      return await this.usersService.findAll();
}
```

but I'm looking for a masive implementation

Comment: What version of NestJS do you use?

Comment: core version 5.0.0-beta.6

Comment: Also stable version 5.0.0 is already released, so I think it better, to switch, and it only few lines in package.json)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have three possible solutions to set guard:

- apply to method (your example)
- apply to controller
- apply globally

Apply to controller:

```
@Controller('cats')
@UseGuards(RolesGuard)
export class CatsController {}
```

Apply guard globally:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
app.useGlobalGuards(new RolesGuard());
```

All examples from guards docs - https://docs.nestjs.com/guards

Comment: Thanks Vladyslav, your answer is very usefull.

Comment: it there a way to apply global guard and remove it for a particular controller

Comment: @DipanshuMahla unfortunately not https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/964